# Google sheets copy and paste row 120 times in the same sheet

Tags: google-sheets

So I have a sheet with about 800 rows. What I need to do is copy and paste each one 120 times. Instead of doing this manually I am hoping there is an automated way to do this in one shot. I have searched for a few things but everything I found had to do with copying the rows conditionally.

I don't need conditions. I just need all, each one of the 800 rows to be duplicated 120 times.

Any help or ideas is greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: You can write a script to do that. How exactly do you want the rows to be copied? Just added to the end?

Comment: I figured it would be a script. I however can not execute that myself. I would want the rows to be cloned under the original.

Comment: Why can't you execute that?

Comment: I simply meant i wouldnt know how to write that script myself from scratch

Comment: I am aware of the Script editor and where I would put it and am familiar with using scripts to do automation in sheets. I just meant I wouldnt know how to write it myself is all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modified @SpiderPig code to clone in a interleaved fashion

```
function duplicateRows() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
      var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()
      var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn()
      var numberOfClones = 120
 for(var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    range = sheet.getRange((i*numberOfClones)+ 1, 1, 1, numColumns);
    sheet.insertRows((i*numberOfClones)+ 2, numberOfClones-1)
    range.copyTo(sheet.getRange((i*numberOfClones)+ 2 , 1, numberOfClones-1, numColumns));
 }
}
```

Also instead of using a loop with range.copyTo(destination) to paste 120 times, you can expand the destination range to 120 rows. It will automatically paste the same value over the entire range.

So instead of this

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 120; i++) {
    range.copyTo(sheet.getRange(numRows * i + 1, 1, numRows, numColumns));
  }
```

you can do this once

```
    range.copyTo(sheet.getRange(numRows * i + 1, 1, 120*numRows, numColumns));
```

Comment: I will be checking this tonight

Comment: I changed this to the correct answer because it did exactly everything I asked in my question. Special Thanks to @SpiderPig for getting the ball started in the right direction. Cheers! Hopefully this helps someone in the future

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script that will copy all the rows in the current sheet 120 times.

```
function duplicateRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
      numRows = sheet.getLastRow(),
      numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn(),
      range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, numRows, numColumns);
  for(var i = 1; i <= 120; i++) {
    range.copyTo(sheet.getRange(numRows * i + 1, 1, numRows, numColumns));
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey so this does work. But it clones the rows under the last one. so the next 800 get cloned starting at line 801. So I have to manually put the clone under the original row. So if row 1 had "my name" and row 2 "your name", this script is printing "my name, your name, my name, your name" instead of "my name, my name, your name, your name". I am going to mark it as correct because it does do the cloning. Thank you @SpiderPig. if there is a way to make it print them the way I stated above. Please let me know. Cheers!